# Is a UWP packaging project for a WPF application "SelfContained"?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, uwp, .net-6.0

I have a .NET6 WPF app and am packaging it with a UWP packaging project. In the past this has worked fine. Now I get an error:

> It is not supported to build or publish a self-contained application
> without specifying a RuntimeIdentifier. You must either specify a
> RuntimeIdentifier or set SelfContained to false.

So which one do I need to do (and where?)? Is a normal WPF app considered SelfContained, or should I just set that to `false`? (And how would I go about doing that?)

I do **not** want to run any command line options since those should not be needed. And notice this is a simple WPF application, and according to [this Microsoft walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) no additional steps should be needed.

Comment: It depends; do you want to ship a self-contained application (i.e. one that includes the .NET runtime)? Or will you expect users to install a shared .NET runtime?

Comment: Also, a note on terminology: "Windows Application Packaging Projects" generate an MSIX package. UWP applications are typically packaged using MSIX but this is not a UWP application; you are generating an MSIX package for a non-UWP application. Describing this as a "UWP packaging project" may lead to some confusion.

MSIX is generally difficult to work with, and if you can avoid it I'd recommend doing so.

Comment: @ReillyWood I want to publish it to the Windows Store. You are correct that it's not really a UWP app, it's a packaged desktop app.

Comment: In that case I believe you will want self-contained - it will be a much better user experience than having users install the .NET runtime separately.

I don't know a ton about packaging projects, but you'll probably want to set <RuntimeIdentifier> in the packaging project or your csproj: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog

Answer (score 0):

A self-contained .NET (Core or 5+) app of any kind always produces a platform-specific executable so you must specify a valid runtime identifier when you build one. This has nothing to do with MSIX or UWP.

A "normal", i.e. created using the built-in template in Visual Studio, WPF app is not self-contained but [framework-dependent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077). This basically means that a user of your app is required to install the .NET runtime before they can run the app. This is usually not an issue for apps that run (only) on Windows, such as for example WPF apps.